# What is the meaning of "music streets" here?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

While watching the 2021 AMAs, I heard Billy Porter as a presenter saying, "It always feels good to be recognized by your peers whether in my hometown, your hometown, or up in these **music streets**. See, I prefer the streets 'cause I **run** them."

Here when he mentioned "music streets," does that mean music scene?
And why did he say "run them"?
I don't think it means he literally "runs" the street.
Please help me understand the sentence.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People always grow up in their streets. That is their neighborhoods. They will commonly describe their neighborhoods as streets. This can also mean the neighborhood of the music *scene* where they used to be known and respected. Running such a neighborhood or scene is a judgement call from one time to another.